# Pyramid settings type conversions

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm getting some settings from the pyramid's `registry.settings`. Unfortunately, I can't figure out why some settings (mainly pyramid-specific ones) are automatically converted, while others (my custom ones) are not.

With `development.ini` containing:

```
pyramid.reload_templates = true
stripe.enabled = false
```

I end up with the settings dictionary like:

```
{
  "pyramid.reload_templates": True,
  "stripe.enabled": "false",
}
```

How can I mark my entries as "convert to bool" as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main() function you'll be getting this key/value pair as a setting and have to do any type conversion necessary, before you pass the dictionary as settings to the Configurator. For example:

```
[app:main]
debug_frobnosticator = True

def main(global_config, **settings):
    from pyramid.settings import asbool
    debug_frobnosticator = asbool(settings.get(
        'debug_frobnosticator', 'false'))
    settings['debug_frobnosticator'] = debug_frobnosticator
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
```

`asbool(s)`
Return the boolean value True if the case-lowered value of string input s is a truthy string. If s is already one of the boolean values True or False, return it.